# NPM RUN BUILD ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, npm-build

[My Error Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCVlp.png)

ERROR in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css (./node_modules/@nuxt/postcss8/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/@nuxt/postcss8/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@nuxt/postcss8/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 30
at /home/simrs/adamklinik/frontend/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css:200:3

I use nuxt.js and tailwind

Comment: I have the same issue and same setup (nuxt.js with tailwind and vuetify). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who stumbles over this issue: I solved it by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67827344/6098257

In my case I just had to set `postcss-custom-properties` to false.

```
build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        "postcss-custom-properties": false
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31272201)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I changed my answer. The link is the direct link to the answer. Since we are in the stackoverflow cosmos this shouldn´t change. No need to vote down...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `npm install` first, then rerun with `npm run build`.

Comment: This didn´t work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do steps:

- npm uninstall @nuxtjs/fontawesome @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons -D
- npm i @nuxtjs/fontawesome @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons -D

Or you can manual update two packages (@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons and @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons) to v6.x